# Method Overridding in Inherited Class

Tags: python, inheritance, inherited

When accessing the object created from extended class by using the base class method, it is returning parent attribute values.
So the only way to return extended attribute values here is to override the base class method display also?

```
class Developer:
  def __init__(self):
    self.__seniority = 'Junior'
    self.skills = ''

  def display(self):
    print('Welcome with {seniority} developer with skills {skills}'.format(
            seniority=self.__seniority, skills = self.skills))

class Python(Developer):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.__seniority = 'Senior'
    self.skills = 'NodeJS'


t1 = Developer()
t2 = Python()
t1.display() -- Welcome with Junior developer with skills
t2.display() -- Welcome with Junior developer with skills NodeJS
```

Comment: Don't make the seniority variable have a double underscore

Comment: ok got the point, but I am not clear with the real purpose of name mangling with double underscore. In my above case as luk2302 mentioned, I can have seniority variable without double underscore which serves my purpose. But won't this cause name mangling in subclass since I am using same variable name "seniority" ? So in which cases I should use double underscore I am confused.